# In which web language can I execute multiple queries with SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, jsp, web, sql-injection

I'm doing a college work about web vulnerabilities, and I need to demonstrate in practice some of those vulnerabilities, especially SQL injection. I developed two applications, one in PHP, and one in JSP, but none of those accepts multiple queries, and I need to execute a `DROP TABLE` from a SQL injection script.

So I already know that `mysql_query()` escapes multiple queries, and `Statement.execute()` too, I haven't tried yet with ASP.NET. But is ASP.NET the only web language that allows that in the simplest query syntax? Like `mysql_query()` is PHP simplest syntax, and `st.execute()` is JSP's simplest syntax, that means that a lot of web applications uses this syntax.

JSP

```
String query = "SELECT * from user; DROP TABLE user;-- ";
st = con.createStatement();
st.execute(query);
```

PHP

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from user; DROP TABLE user;-- ");
```

Edit: I was not very clear, I'm making a vulnerable login application, and I need to `DROP` a table with a SQL injection, like in a query:

```
"SELECT * FROM user where user ='".$_POST['user']."' AND pass = md5('".$_POST['pass']."')";
```

I pass in the user field '; DROP TABLE user; -- ', my question is, which web language allows me to do that **without using specific functions like `mysqli_multi_query()`?**

Comment: Read about `TRANSACTION`.

Comment: Both languages support multiple queries to be executed. Also php! (Though the deprecated mysql_* functions not.)

Comment: Doing "Little Bobby Tables"? http://xkcd.com/327/  ADO.Net supports multiple queries separated by semicolon.  PHP should as well...?

Comment: The PHP MySQLi extension supports multiple queries. [PHP MySQLi Multiple Statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php).

Comment: Yeah, i know about PHP mysqli_multi_query(), but i need a web language that allows multiple queries in the simplest query syntax. Like PHP's simplest syntax is mysql_query()

Comment: Any language which doesn't force you to use prepared statements...

Comment: I don't want to prevent SQL Injections, i want to demonstrate different forms, and her danger, but i can't execute a DROP TABLE in any of those languages

Comment: @OIS Like what? That's what I need to know ..

Comment: You can demonstrate replacing password with t" OR 1;# or some of the  utf8 injections

Comment: @OIS i need to DROP the table, not grant access...

Comment: What is wrong with just calling mysql_query() twice? Once to select and the second to drop.

Comment: Exactly @EricJ. i wanna do that! Which language allows me to build a query that will execute multiple queries? PHP and Java is already protected to that, escaping multiple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility would be that you could try some roundabout way. Such as having PHP call up a shellexec() and run all the SQL statements through the MySQL console command line via PHP. I am not even sure this can be done, given the interactive nature of the command line here.

Unfortunately it won't really be a way that you can say is common to be used. It seems like all the input suggests that it just can't be done directly these days. At least not the multi-query injection limitation. But that doesn't mean that there are not other SQL injection attacks that can happen.

The one thing that I can think of is using comments or sub-query. With comments you would have to spend a lot of time crafting a solution whereby you add a "--" to the end of your injected SQL to close out the rest of the SQL statement. This would be problematic if there are any line breaks after where your code goes. But using sub-queries seems more possible.

For sub-queries what you would do is probably inject into a search query a value that goes into a WHERE clause.

Example...

Start with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE first_name = 'bobby'; -- Bobby being an unsanitized value.
```

Becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE first_name = 'bobby' AND (DELETE FROM students WHERE student_id > 0) = true AND '' = '';
```

In my second example I injected this:

```
' AND (DELETE FROM students WHERE student_id > 0) = true AND '' = '
```

Which utilizes the sub-query method to inject an action statement. Check out the page on the SQL standards: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php

Comment: Nice trying @pthurdmond but i still got an error! I put it online in a temp server, look what i'm trying to do, you can enter an username and password, and i debugged the result! Can you try it?http://54.232.204.7

Comment: I find it kinda funny that every time someone posts SQL-injection vulnerable code on StackOverflow, they get yelled at.  Yet, no one can actually *demonstrate* a working SQL-injection attack.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yeah, I am/was concerned that would happen to me here as well. I honestly can't say I have spent much time on the subject. I certainly have never tried anything out along these lines. So I am just basing this off of my general knowledge of how it works. This is more of an idea that might work. But I won't go as far as to say that it absolutely will. Just trying to give the guy some direction and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a language limitation by any stretch. Any server-side language for the web can execute multiple queries (I do it all the time). But your question doesn't really make a lot of sense. Are you wanting to pass it a massive SQL file to do a bunch of operations? Or are you wanting to do data/event specific operations such as your basic CRUD functions (Create, Read, Update, Delete)?

All the syntax will be simple. But if you really want to obfuscate it to simplify it further then use an ORM, such as the Eloquent system that comes with the Laravel framework.

Though honestly, I think you just need to spend a bunch of time learning SQL and the web language of your preference. I will say this, PHP is where the vast majority of web development happens. Lots of resources on it.

Edit:
Being that you are truly set on running multiple queries from the same call you can use the function described here: http://raamdev.com/2008/multiple-query-problems-with-mysql_query/

A.K.A.: mysqli::multi_query - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Try something like this: mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dbName`.`tableName`') or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I think he wants to illustrate dropping a table through SQL injections on _purpose_ for his college project. It doesn't sound like he's looking on creating a full function app...

Comment: Excatly @Jason ! I can't found a web language that execute multiples queries to drop a table with SQL Injection

Comment: Ah, I get it. You are right in saying mysql_query() in PHP does not support that. Have you checked out it's replacement, mysqli_query()? I didn't see anything in the documentation about that limitation (though mysql_query does mention that in the docs). Check it out: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Actually, check this. There is some functionality for it: http://raamdev.com/2008/multiple-query-problems-with-mysql_query/

Comment: Thank you @pthurmond! But mysqli_query() is also protected, like says in the docs "For non-DML queries (not INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE), this function is similar to calling mysqli_real_query() followed by either mysqli_use_result() or mysqli_store_result()." she only executes one query!

Comment: Yeah @pthurdmon, in php i can use mysqli_multi_query(), but that's my point, who uses that? I can't say that PHP is vulnerable, because a lot of web application uses mysql_query(); so i want to know which other web language have that vulnerability in her simplest query sintax! ;)

Comment: Honestly, you might not find one these days. The bad ones that don't filter this out probably got left behind and abandoned. You could check Ruby, ColdFusion, Classic ASP, ASP.NET, or C#.NET. Of those the most likely candidates would be ColdFusion and Classic ASP.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually strange that you cannot SQL Inject your own vulnerable code with the 'DROP TABLE method.

I would try using mysqli functions, including the multi-query one, that should be mysqli_multi_query()

Please notice that PHP support for mysqli has been introduced in PHP 5.

EDIT: Just read your comments about being aware of this function. I think this is the simplest way though.

Answer (score -1):

It's not the web language that's the issue.  It's MySQL that doesn't allow multiple statements in a single prepare.  See the documentation on prepared statements:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Near the end of that page there is this snippet:

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by “;” characters

That will make it harder to use the canonical `'Bobby'; DROP TABLE STUDENTS;'`.

Comment: That's what i'm talking about! I want to drop the table! I want to know which web language allows me to do that whitout using especific functions like mysqli_multi_query()

Comment: The reason for multi_query is because mysql doesn't like multiple statements in a string.  So any other language would have to use the same work-around.